# Google maps marker doesn't show up javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I am struggling with the marker on a custom map. The map centers on the right place, but the marker doesn't show up on that place. Someone has the same problem already solved?
Thank you a lot for your help!

```
  function initialize() {
                var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
                var map_options = {
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.840164,4.33244),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP
                    },
                    panControl: false,
                    panControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                    },
                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
                    },
                    scaleControl: false,
                    scaleControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
                    },
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    streetViewControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
                    }
                  }

                var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
              }

        function addMarker(feature) {
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: feature.position,
                    icon: 'locationpointer.png',

                    map: map_canvas
                  });
                }

                var features = [
                  {
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.840164,4.33244),
                  }
                ];

                for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
                  addMarker(feature);
                }




        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your addMarker function in the initialize function so the markers are added *after* the map is initialized, not before.  You have 2 options for initializing the map property of the marker either 1. make it global or 2. pass it in to the addMarker function (as below).  Also note that map_canvas is a HTML DOM element, not a google.maps.Map, the name of that variable is "map".

```
function initialize() {
  var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var map_options = {
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 16,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.840164,4.33244),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP
                },
                panControl: false,
                panControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                },
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
                },
                scaleControl: false,
                scaleControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
                },
                streetViewControl: false,
                streetViewControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
                }
              }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)

  var features = [
      {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.840164,4.33244),
      }
  ];

  for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
    addMarker(feature, map);
  }
}

function addMarker(feature, map) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: feature.position,
                icon: 'locationpointer.png',
                map: map
   });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it didn't work for me.   `var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
  
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: map,
   icon: '##',
            title: "##."
        }); `  that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to add the marker to the map.
Either use marker.setMap(map) or pass it via marker properties as you try to do.
But in your code the map and map_canvas variables are not in the global scope, this means your addMarker function cannot add it and map: map_canvas is null

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    icon: 'locationpointer.png',
    **map: map_canvas**
});
```

You would have to slightly change your code to pass the map into the addMarker function.